# how to get direct child nodes not sub-child nodes with same tag name xml minidom python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, minidom

i have using xml minidom to get some data from xml files but unable to get desire result... try many codes from this site related to xml minidom but fail.. here is my sample xml file..

```
<computer>
    <parts>
        <text>Required</text>
    </parts>
    <parts>
        <text>Required</text>
        <parts>
            <text>?Not Required</text>
        </parts>
        <parts>
            <text>?Not Required</text>
        </parts>
    </parts>
    <parts>
        <text>Required</text>
        <parts>
            <text>Not Required</text>
        </parts>
    </parts>
    <parts>
        <text>Required</text>
   </parts>
</computer>
```

i want to get text that is "required" but get output like that

```
Required
Required
Not Required
Not Required
Required
Not Required
Required
```

here is my code sample that get all text from file but i need text inside such tags that are direct child of parent tag...

```
from xml.dom import minidom
file=('d:\sample.xml')
xmldoc=minidom.parse(file)
parentnode = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('computer')
for node in parentnode:
    alist=node.getElementsByTagName('text')
    for a in alist:
        t=a.childNodes[0].nodeValue
        print authortext
```

desire output that i want

```
Required
Required
Required
Required
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` gets all descendants. You need all *children*.

Comment: i need all its direct descendants not indirect descendants... u can say i need father child names not names of his grandchild names...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless your actual XML is much more complicated, you can navigate the DOM tree and get the child nodes you want from the `text` children in the `parts` nodes that are children of `computer`:

```
import xml.dom.minidom

file=('sample.xml')
xmldoc=xml.dom.minidom.parse(file)
computerNode = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('computer')
for computerChild in computerNode:
    for parts in computerChild.childNodes:
       for partsChild in parts.childNodes:
          if partsChild.nodeType == xml.dom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE: 
             if partsChild.tagName == 'text':
                print partsChild.childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

To use XPath, as I had suggested before, and simpler DOM navigation, its best to use the [Element Tree API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Comment: To use this you need the *dom-xpath* module linked above. You need to install the module in your system (download the package, unzip, enter directory, run `python setup.py install`). After the module is installed, your program will find it and run.

Comment: i have install py-dom-xpath using easy_install but i give error like  XPathParseError: Syntax error:
/computer/parts/text

Comment: It might be a bug, since it works in my installation (Mac). Anyway, to use XPath, it's best to use *etree* as I suggest in the link above. I fixed your code using pure DOM which should work.